# Grothendieck group of a symmetric monoidal category is a lambda ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, category-theory, monoidal-categories

I understand that taking the Grothendieck group of a braided monoidal (abelian) category gives us a commutative ring and that taking that of a symmetric monoidal (abelian) category gives us a $\lambda$-ring.  Now, I have simply seen this (latter) fact stated on the internet by reputable mathematicians, but I have not been able to find a reference explaining *how* one gets all that extra structure ($\lambda$-rings seem quite complicated!) from one extra property that symmetric monoidal categories have.

I was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction or shed some light on the details?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The $\lambda$-structure is given by taking exterior powers. This is the main motivation I know for defining $\lambda$-rings in the first place. (You need an action of $S_n$ on an $n^{th}$ tensor power $V^{\otimes n}$ to define the exterior power, which is what being symmetric monoidal gets you; in the braided monoidal case you only get an action of $B_n$.)

Comment: For the sake of completeness: In a linear symmetric monoidal category with (finite) colimits, the **$n$th antisymmetric power** of an object $V$ is the coequalizer of the maps $\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) \sigma : V^{\otimes n} \to V^{\otimes n}$. The usual properties hold when the tensor product commutes with (finite) colimits. In characteristic $0$ one can then define exterior powers as antisymmetric powers. For positive characteristic there seems to be no reasonable definition up to now (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/70607/exterior-powers-in-tensor-categories).